# ics URL is not showing any event in google calendar

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am generating following ics file URL to import into google calendar and when I am trying to import the calendar is imported successfully however the event is not showing in google calendar.  I have tried downloading this ics file and then importing into google calendar, for this I am getting message "importing 0 of 1 event" and nothing is shown in the calendar. The same URL is working for Mac calendar. Any idea how to fix this for google calendar

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//SNSNSNS CLOUD//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Sunny B's  Inspections
X-WR-CALDESC:Sunny B's  Inspections
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20210210T070000Z
DTEND:20210210T073000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210209T123900Z
UID:3
SUMMARY:Test Inspection
DESCRIPTION: test description
LOCATION:
END:VEVENT
```

**UPDATE**
With Following comment I have changed UID and this is my new .ics file hosed on some URL however when I am importing this file URL in Google calendar it is not showing any event. It is also not syncing any update to events

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://TEST CLOUD//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Sunny B's  Inspections
X-WR-CALDESC:Sunny B's  Inspections
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20210216T060000Z
DTEND:20210216T063000Z
DTSTAMP:20210211T112000Z
UID:dev-fresnoca-inspections-3
SUMMARY:Test Inspection  for Cannabis Business Owner Background Form BC-20-6
DESCRIPTION:Inspector: Sunny B | url: http://dev.lvh.me:4200/#/explore/records/17/59
LOCATION:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I have quite a similar problem, but it doesn't seem to be caused by UID: Import ICS file to an existing calendar works, but reading the URL of the same file doesn't retrieve anything. No idea where it comes from...

Answer (score 2):

Based on [RFC 5545 Unique Identifier (UID)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.7), the UID **MUST** be a globally unique identifier.

> A good method to assure uniqueness is to put the
> domain name or a domain literal IP address of the host on which
> the identifier was created on the right-hand side of an "@", and
> on the left-hand side, put a combination of the current calendar
> date and time of day (i.e., formatted in as a DATE-TIME value)
> along with some other currently unique (perhaps sequential)
> identifier available on the system (for example, a process id
> number).  Using a DATE-TIME value on the left-hand side and a
> domain name or domain literal on the right-hand side makes it
> possible to guarantee uniqueness since no two hosts should be
> using the same domain name or IP address at the same time.  Though
> other algorithms will work, it is RECOMMENDED that the right-hand
> side contain some domain identifier (either of the host itself or
> otherwise) such that the generator of the message identifier can
> guarantee the uniqueness of the left-hand side within the scope of
> that domain.

---

I tried replacing your UID with a unique identifier and the event was successfully imported.

**Sample ICS:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//SNSNSNS CLOUD//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Sunny B's  Inspections
X-WR-CALDESC:Sunny B's  Inspections
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20210210T070000Z
DTEND:20210210T073000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20210209T123900Z
UID:TESTDOMAIN20210210T070000
SUMMARY:Test Inspection
DESCRIPTION: test description
LOCATION:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information I have updated UID and then tried again and google calendar shown my event but later after few occurrences it was stopped showing the event. I am using ics URL stored on azure blob service. One more thing I have observed that when I added calendar  URL and then if the event has been changed I am updating the ICS file however those changes in not getting reflected in google calendar. Do you have any idea what's wrong and where I can debug this? The same scenario working for ical(mac)

Comment: Does UUID needs to be change when there is change in event???

Comment: When I tried to change an event detail, like for example the summary, It did not require me to update the UID. It was successfully imported when tried manually

Comment: I will try to do some research regarding your concern with the ics URL in azure blob service. I cannot replicate this in my end due to my limited environment platform available

Comment: But as for my understanding, you might need to seek support from Microsoft as well since the ics file can be manually imported successfully in Google Calendar

Comment: Yes I am seeing some weird behaviour in google calendar. When I import the ics file through URL sometimes the event is not showing immediately, google calendar is taking time to reflect it. In between if I changed the event date and republished the new ics file the google calendar is not showing the updated date. I am struggling to know how google is sync the updated changes from ics file URL. is there anything to do with ics file format/UUID/Sequence?? The same thing works as expected in Ical (Mac)